# How can I test Canvas elements in a Vue.js test?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, html5-canvas, vue-test-utils

I have a handful of vue component methods like this:

```
    showPhotoOnTarget(photoCanvas, targetCanvas) {
      let imgData = photoCanvas
        .getContext("2d")
        .getImageData(0, 0, photoCanvas.width, photoCanvas.height);
      targetCanvas.width = photoCanvas.width;
      targetCanvas.height = photoCanvas.height;
      targetCanvas.getContext("2d").putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
    }
```

In my test setup I tried mocking the Canvas stuff like this:

```
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        currentPhotoCanvas: {
          getContext: () => ({
            getImageData: jest.fn(),
            putImageData: jest.fn()
          })
        }
      },
      getters: {
        "snap/getCurrentPhotoCanvas": state => state.currentPhotoCanvas
      }
```

`showPhotoOnTarget` is being called on the mount hook, like this:

```
    const photoCanvasRef = this.$refs.photoTargetCanvas;
    this.showPhotoOnTarget(this.photoCanvas, photoCanvasRef);
```

and `$refs` is being mocked in the mount options like this:

```
const $refs = {
    photoTargetCanvas: {}
  };
```

However, when I run the test, I get this error:  `TypeError: Failed to execute 'putImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': parameter 1 is not of type 'ImageData'.`

Is it possible to mock Canvas functions like this in my vue tests?  If so, can somebody tell me how to go about setting up the tests?  I'm not very familiar with Canvas, which may be part of the problem.

Comment: Can you show how `showPhotoOnTarget()` is invoked?

Comment: @tony19 The question has been updated.